# Sinatra: route doesn't route when deployed to Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra

In my app.rb:

route **'/'** is routed properly, I can see all the categories on the page (so my app does have all the necessary information in TechBomagCategory table).

```
get '/' do
  @categories = Category.all
  erb :categories
end
```

And then

```
Category.all.each do |category|
  get '/' + category.title do
    erb :products
  end
end
```

doesn't create necessary routes. When I go to any **'/' + category.title** page, 404 page occurs.
Notice that on my local machine everything works as expected, all the pages are rendered perfectly fine.

What went wrong, how should I fix it?

Comment: I just created the same style of routing and pushed it to Heroku and it is working fine. http://nameless-headland-2006.herokuapp.com/foo. You can see a gist of my simple implementation at https://gist.github.com/bigtunacan/3a8e967bee58aed238d4.  Can you provide additional information or better yet a git repo?

Comment: @bigtunacan, thank you for trying to help, I've just found a solution - I needed to restart heroku. It behaved like categories table was simultaneously empty (because .each didn't run properly) and filled (because categories = Category.all) worked. I'm not sure why, any ideas?

Comment: Strange; sounds like some type of caching issue. Could be somewhere in Heroku's stack or the ORM. What ORM are you using?

Comment: @bigtunacan, Active Record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It figures simple

```
heroku restart
```

helps. I guess that route was nonfunctional because it was created when my **categories** table wasn't yet seeded.